# mvc 5: Optional model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a model called Project

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int    ID      { set; get; }
    public string Title   { set; get; }
    public string Image   { set; get; }
    public double? gained { set; get; }
}
```

I use this model with two stored procedures one returns all the properties and the other without the property `gained`. And I got this error

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Test.Models.Project'. A member of the type, 'Gained', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

I don't want to write separate models for each stored procedure.
How to solve that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datareader is kind of dumb in the sense that it will only match what was sent back to it.  If a column is missing, it fails, as you can see.

The easiest way to solve this would be to update your second SELECT statement in your stored procedure to pass back a column named gained.

```
SELECT ID, Title, Image, NULL as gained FROM table
```

Here, we are passing back no data (NULL) as the gained column.  This should make the data reader happy, keep you from needing multiple models and not send back any extra data.

The other possibility would be to use inheritance in your models.  Have a base model that does not include gained, and have a second model that inherits from the base model that does include gained.

```
public class ProjectBase
{
    [Key]
    public int    ID      { set; get; }
    public string Title   { set; get; }
    public string Image   { set; get; }
}

public class ProjectGained : ProjectBase{
    public double? gained { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am thinking of if there any way to write a custom attribute like [NotMapped] to solve the proble. The solution you suggested is good but will not work for my case because I have huge number of properties in that model

Comment: @MohammedEssamHelewa - not that I am aware of, you might need to go with the inherited model route if you have multiple properties that aren't mapped between the two returns.